# Python: for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a for loop to add values to keys in an established 
dictionary. However, I keep getting the last value instead of all of the
 values. What I am doing wrong?

My current dictionary looks like:

```
growth_dict = dict.fromkeys(conc[1:9], '')

growth_dict = {'100 ug/ml': '', '12.5 ug/ml': '', '50 ug/ml': '', 
    '0 ug/ml': '', '6.25 ug/ml': '', '25 ug/ml': '', '3.125 ug/ml': '', 
    '1.5625 ug/ml': ''}

cols_list = numpy.loadtxt(fn, skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,9), unpack=True)

numer = (0.301)*960 #numerator

for i in cols_list:

    N = i[-1]
    No = i[0]
    denom = (math.log(N/No)) #denominator
    g = numer/denom
```

When I run the program and type "growth_dict," it returns my dictionary with only the last value as the key:

```
growth_dict = {'100 ug/ml': 131.78785283808514, '12.5 ug/ml': 131.78785283808514, 
    '50 ug/ml': 131.78785283808514, '0 ug/ml': 131.78785283808514, 
    '6.25 ug/ml': 131.78785283808514, '25 ug/ml': 131.78785283808514, 
    '3.125 ug/ml': 131.78785283808514, '1.5625 ug/ml': 131.78785283808514}
```

Comment: What output do you get when running this program? What output did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the value of the `conc[j]` dictionary entry each time you do this:

```
growth_dict[conc[j]] = g
```

If you want each successive `g` to be appended to the dictionary entry, try something like:

```
for j in conc:
    # The first time each key is tested, an empty list will be created
    if not instanceof(growth_dict[conc[j]], list):
        growth_dict[conc[j]] = []
    growth_dict[conc[j]].append(g)
```

Comment: But I thought that dictionaries don't have the attribute "append?"

Comment: @ttdinh: it is a dictionary of lists - each list does have .append()

Answer (score 1):

You could also save a lot of effort in loading your data by doing

```
cols_list = numpy.loadtxt(fn, skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,9), unpack=True)
```

Comment: thank you! this is my first programming class, so i'm still trying to figure out this stuff